# How to alter PATH within a shell script?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, path, cygwin

I have several projects that require me to change versions of Java/Grails/Maven. I'm trying to handle this with some scripts that would make the changes. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/dev/Java/jdk1.5.0_22
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export GRAILS_HOME=/cygdrive/c/dev/grails-1.0.3
export PATH=$GRAILS_HOME/bin:$PATH
export MAVEN_HOME=/cygdrive/c/dev/apache-maven-2.0.11
export PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
which java
which grails
which mvn
```

When this executes, it successfully changes the PATH within the context of the script, but then the script ends, and no change has been accomplished.

How can I run a script in a way to change the PATH in for the shell in which I am currently working?

I'm using Cygwin.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have to use `source` or `eval` or to spawn a new shell.

When you run a shell script a new *child* shell is spawned. This *child* shell will execute the script commands. The *father* shell environment will remain untouched by anything happens in the *child* shell.

There are a lot of different techniques to manage this situation:

1. Prepare a file **sourcefile** containg a list of commands to `source` in the current shell:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/dev/Java/jdk1.5.0_22
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```

   and then source it

   ```
   source sourcefile
   ```

   note that there is no need for a sha-bang at the begin of the **sourcefile**, but it will work with it.
2. Prepare a script **evalfile.sh** that prints the command to set the environment:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   echo "export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/dev/Java/jdk1.5.0_22"
   echo "export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
   ```

   and then `eval`uate it:

   ```
   eval `evalfile.sh`
   ```
3. Configure and run a new shell:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/dev/Java/jdk1.5.0_22
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

   exec /bin/bash
   ```

   note that when you type `exit` in this shell, you will return to the *father* one.
4. Put an alias in your `~/.bashrc`:

   ```
   alias prepare_environ='export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/dev/Java/jdk1.5.0_22; export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH;'
   ```

   and call it when needed:

   ```
   prepare_environ
   ```

Comment: I noticed that `source` works only for `bash`. Output for `ksh`: `/bin/ksh: source: not found`, for `sh`: `sh: 0: source: not found`. The answer below should be considered for these shells.

Comment: @dannylo, you are right but the question is clearly `bash` centric.

Comment: Is 'export' required with $PATH - which presumably exists already?

Comment: @esskov usually it isn't. I remember only an old old version of sh on AIX that required it (circa 1992) but, probably, it was some sort of bug.

Answer (score 20):

You could do that by using the *source* builtin:

```
. script_name
```

Some shells provide an alias named *source*:

```
source script_name
```