# What does command eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)" actually do?

Tags: shell, macos, syntax, homebrew

Homebrew requires us to add `eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)` to `~/.zprofile`. What does this actually evaluate to and what does this accomplish?

I am a bit new to shell scripting. I know `$var` is used to refer to a variable named var but that's about it. What is the meaning of putting a path inside of `$()`? Also is `shellenv` an argument here and what does it signify?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$()` is [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution).   It executes the command inside the parentheses and returns the output of that command.

It's often used to get the output of a program into a variable.  e.g.

```
$ month=$(date +%m)
$ echo $month
02
```

or to use the output of one program as args for another, e.g.

```
$ printf '%s\n' $(date +%B)
February
```

(ok, yeah, `printf` is a contrived example because just running `date +%B` produces the same output...but it does demonstrate how it works).

The command inside the parentheses may be as simple or as complex as you need, from a single program to a long pipeline of commands.  e.g. I often use commands like the following to remove old kernel packages from my Debian system:

```
apt-get purge $(dlocate -k | grep '6\.0\.0-[245]')
```

BTW, you may also see scripts using backticks (`) for this. This is an old, obsolete form of command substitution, supported for legacy reasons but shouldn't be used in new scripts.

When used with `eval`, it causes your shell to execute the output.  In this case, running `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv` returns a bunch of text like `var=value` and `eval` runs them in your current shell, thus setting those variables to the required values.

From `help eval` in bash:

> `eval`: `eval [arg ...]`
>
> Execute arguments as a shell command.
>
> Combine ARGs into a single string, use the result as input to the shell,
> and execute the resulting commands.
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns exit status of command or success if command is null.

Try running `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv` by itself to see what output it produces.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That was really it.
I first tried running /opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv with eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv) still in ~/.zprofile but it gave no output so got a bit confused. Then I removed it and it gave a bunch of export commands which clearly show how it appends brew to $PATH. 

Thanks for help!

Comment: @Osbridge `brew shellenv` not giving any output at all under some circumstances is explained by `brew help shellenv` (mentioned in a recent answer here: [Command output evaluation not working in Bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/735710)).

Comment: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv has no output. I have no idea why in MacOS - they make everything so complicated? I just want to apend the PATH and for that i am searching around for last 3+ hours.

Answer (score 4):

It exports environment variables needed for brew to work. For example, if I run it without `eval` then this is what it outputs in fish shell:

```bash
$ /opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv

set -gx HOMEBREW_PREFIX "/opt/homebrew";
set -gx HOMEBREW_CELLAR "/opt/homebrew/Cellar";
set -gx HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY "/opt/homebrew";
set -q PATH; or set PATH ''; set -gx PATH "/opt/homebrew/bin" "/opt/homebrew/sbin" $PATH;
set -q MANPATH; or set MANPATH ''; set -gx MANPATH "/opt/homebrew/share/man" $MANPATH;
set -q INFOPATH; or set INFOPATH ''; set -gx INFOPATH "/opt/homebrew/share/info" $INFOPATH;
```

Then `eval` actually executes those `set` commands.

Important to note that this outputs nothing if it has already been loaded into the session.